# transfer collection to treeset and than back to collection

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I have `Collection<String> collection`, and I want to remove duplicates,
(I want to use treeset in order to remove duplicates)
So how can I tranfer that collection to TreeSet and than return it back to collection?

Thanks in advance.
George

Comment: open treeset class and read its javadoc and its methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply achieve your requirement by following the steps given below -

```
       Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<>();

        collection.add("data1");
        collection.add("data1");
        collection.add("data2");
        collection.add("data3");

        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<>();

        set.addAll(collection);
        collection.clear();
        collection.addAll(set);
        System.out.println(collection);
```

It will remove the duplicate `data1` and give output:

> [data1, data2, data3]

Answer (score 0):

`Collection` is not a concrete type : it is an interface.
So you cannot instantiate directly it.
Now as `TreeSet` is a `Collection` implementation, you could assign the `TreeSet` object to a `Collection` variable.   It will be transparent for the client that manipulates a `Collection`.

**Footprint**

You should also be aware that a `Set` has a more important footprint than a ordered collection as a `List`.  So if the `Collection` contains many elements, using a `List` may make sense as the clients will manipulate a `Collection`  variable.

**Ordered**

A `TreeSet` uses the natural order of the elements (or which one of a `Comparator`) and not the order of appearance/insertion of the elements in the `Collection`.
So the order of the elements may change if you use a `TreeSet`.  If the Collection is ordered as a sequence and you want to maintain it, using a `LinkedHashSet` is more appropriate.